Blitzstein and Hwang Conditional Expectation question 39
Question: A group of n friends often go out for dinner together. At their dinners, they play “credit
card roulette” to decide who pays the bill. This means that at each dinner, one person
is chosen uniformly at random to pay the entire bill (independently of what happens at
the other dinners).
(a) Find the probability that in k dinners, no one will have to pay the bill more than
once (do not simplify for the case k <= n, but do simplify fully for the case k > n).
(b) Find the expected number of dinners it takes in order for everyone to have paid at
least once (you can leave your answer as a finite sum of simple-looking terms).
(c) Alice and Bob are two of the friends. Find the covariance between how many times
Alice pays and how many times Bob pays in k dinners (simplify fully).
My solution:
part a): I obtained the solution $1 * \frac{n-1}{n} * \frac{n-2}{n} * ... * \frac{n-k+1}{n}$ for $k \le n$. For $k>n$ I got $0$ because if $k>n$, someone must have paid twice.
part b): This is a typical coupon's collector's problem so the answer is $1 + \frac{n}{n-1} + ... + \frac{n}{1}$
However I am struggling with part c). This is what I have done so far:

Let $A$ be the number of times Alice has paid and $B$ be the number of times Bob has paid. Then $A ~ Bin(k,\frac{1}{n})$ and $B ~ Bin(k,\frac{1}{n})$.
$Cov(A, B) = E(AB) - E(A)E(B) = E(AB) - (\frac{k}{n})^2$. But i don't know how to evaluate $E(AB)$

Any help would be greatlt appreciated.

Here's a hint : Write $A$ and $B$ as sum of indicator random variables!
Let me know if you need more hints, I will be glad to help as edits.
